# Варианты оптимизации большой таблицы?

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица с большим количеством данных. Если количество записей достигнет 2 млн то в среднем операции станут медленнее выполнятся.

Какие способы повышения производительности доступны, без переписывания запросов и изменения полей таблицы или создания еще таблиц?
Можно ли как то разбить такую таблицу на несколько подтаблиц?

Comment: Оптимизация "впрок"? поверьте, это ещё большее зло, чем мифическое снижение производительности. Да и откуда Вы взяли именно 2 миллиона? PS. 2kk - это вовсе не большая таблица... так, чуть больше, чем средненькая.

Comment: партиционирование, создание индексов под имеющиеся запросы